# c++ Reading Element from Vector printing same element at each index

Tags: c++, vector

I had an algorithm which i implemented in JAVA, but i want to test the performance of algorithm in C/C++ with MPI and OpenMP. So i am re writing the code. I haven't touched C++ in years, so i need some advice and guidance. I am putting Objects of Class `Task` in a vector and trying to check values of all elements using for loop.

Here is code of my `Task.h` file. I have created `tostring` function to print all the values of the object.

```
   #include <vector>
   #include <string>

   //for std::vector
   #ifndef TASK_H
   #define  TASK_H


   class Task {
   public:
       Task();
       Task(const Task& orig);
       Task(int identity, float val, long st, long et, long ext, std::vector<int> deplist2, std::vector<int> pretask2);
       void setTId(int identity) ;
       int getTId() ;
       void setVal(float val) ;
       float getVal() ;
       long getStarttime() ;
       void setStarttime(long value) ;
       long getEndtime() ;
       void setEndtime(long value) ;
       long getExectime() ;
       void setExectime(long value) ;
       std::vector<int> getDeplist() ;
       void setDeplist(std::vector<int> value);
       std::vector<int> getPretask() ;
       void setPretask(std::vector<int> value);
       std::string toString();
       virtual ~Task();
   private:

   };

   #endif   /* TASK_H */
```

`toString()` function of `Task.cpp`, Below is Task.cpp

```
   #include "Task.h"
   #include <vector>  //for std::vector
   #include <string>  //for std::string
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>

   using namespace std;
   int id;
   float value;
   long starttime;
   long endtime;
   long exectime;
   std::vector<int> deplist;
   std::vector<int> pretask;

   void Task::setTId(int identity) {
    id = identity;
   }

   int Task::getTId() {
       return id;
   }

   void Task::setVal(float val) {
       value = val;
   }

   float Task::getVal() {
       return value;
   }

   long Task::getStarttime() {
    return starttime;
   }

   void Task::setStarttime(long value) {
    starttime = value;
   }

   long Task::getEndtime() {
    return endtime;
   }

   void Task::setEndtime(long value) {
    endtime = value;
   }

   long Task::getExectime() {
    return exectime;
   }

   void Task::setExectime(long value) {
    exectime = value;
   }

   std::vector<int> Task::getDeplist() {
    return deplist;
   }

   void Task::setDeplist(std::vector<int> value) {
       deplist = value;
   }

   std::vector<int> Task::getPretask() {
       return pretask;
   }

   void Task::setPretask(std::vector<int> value) {
       pretask = value;
   }

   string Task::toString() {
    std::ostringstream oss;

    int pSize = pretask.size();
    int depSize = deplist.size();
    string returnStr = "";
    cout << "printing " << id << endl;


    oss << "\n[ id = "<< id;

    oss << " , val = " << value << " startTime = " << starttime;

    oss << " , endTime = " << endtime;

oss << " , execTime = " << exectime;

oss << " depList = @/ ";
for (int var = 0; var < depSize; var++) {

    int tmp = deplist.at(var);
    oss << tmp << " , ";

}
oss << " @/ Pretasks = $<< ";

for (int var = 0; var < pSize; var++) {

    int tmp = pretask.at(var);
    oss << tmp << " , ";

    }

oss << " >>$ ] \n";
returnStr.append(oss.str());

return returnStr;
   }

   Task::Task() {

   }

   Task::Task(int identity, float val, long st, long et, long ext,
    std::vector<int> deplist2, std::vector<int> pretask2) {
id = identity;
value = val;
starttime = st;
endtime = et;
exectime = ext;
deplist = deplist2;
pretask = pretask2;
cout << "added task " << id<<endl;
   }

   Task::Task(const Task& orig) {

   }

   Task::~Task() {

   }
```

My main function creates a vector and inseert objects like following

```
 std::vector<Task> taskList;
 taskList.reserve(num_tasks); // Set size of vector

    // populate the tasks
{

    int i;
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared (taskList) reduction(+:taskLength)
    for (i = 0; i < num_tasks; i++) {
        int rand = min + (std::rand() % (max - min + 1));
        taskLength+=rand;
        std::vector<int> deplist2;
        std::vector<int> pretask2;

        taskList.push_back(Task(i, rand, 0, 0, 0, deplist2,  pretask2));
        //taskList.insert(i,Task(i, rand, 0, 0, 0, deplist2,  pretask2));
                    cout <<i<<endl;
    }
}

{
    for (int var = 0; var < num_tasks; var++) {
        Task tmpT=taskList[var];
                    string prt= tmpT.toString();
                    cout << var << " "<<prt;
    }

}
```

But my output looks like

```
  printing 9
  0 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  1 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  2 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  3 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  4 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  5 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  6 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  7 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  8 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ] 
  printing 9
  9 
  [ id = 9 , val = 12 startTime = 0 , endTime = 0 , execTime = 0 depList = @/  @/ Pretasks = $<<  >>$ ]
```

So far i have tried using vector.at() method to access the function but it does the same thing. Any idea will help. Thanks :)

Update 1: Added Task.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Soluntion, Problem was members of Task class were not private. So changed my header file `Task.cpp` and added all the members in private section

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//for std::vector
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

class Task {
public:
    Task();
//Task(const Task& orig);
    Task(int identity, float val, long st, long et, long ext,
        std::vector<int> deplist2, std::vector<int> pretask2);
    void setTId(int identity);
    int getTId();
    void setVal(float val);
    float getVal();
    long getStarttime();
    void setStarttime(long value);
    long getEndtime();
    void setEndtime(long value);
    long getExectime();
    void setExectime(long value);
    std::vector<int> getDeplist();
    void setDeplist(std::vector<int> value);
    std::vector<int> getPretask();
    void setPretask(std::vector<int> value);
    std::string toString();
    virtual ~Task();
private:
    int id;
    float value;
    long starttime;
    long endtime;
    long exectime;
    vector<int> deplist;
    vector<int> pretask;
};

    #endif  /* TASK_H */
```

This is the thing now i think actually worked (Sorry still learning). LOLz . Remove copy constructor with

```
Task(const Task& orig)
```

Comment: Whether those are public or private makes no difference to the output of your program .In your original code you didn't have those members at all.

Comment: @M.M, Sorry i don't have that much knowledge about c++, but whatever it worked for me. :) :P In Java i declare most of members such classes private . It suddenly came to me to make these members private.

Comment: @M.M Another thing i found default constructor ` Processor(const Processor& orig) ` with const paramter. That was the problem i think. :P

Comment: That's a copy-constructor, not a default constructor.  In this answer you have variables `int id;`  `float value;` etc. You claimed you "made them private", but in your question *you did not have those at all*.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for correcting me there. Yeah my code do have those mebers look at `Task.cpp`.

Comment: OK, Task.cpp wasn't posted when I first commented. So what you've really done is changed *global variables* to *class member variables*. Originally they were not members at all.

Comment: @Bob__ it makes no different so far as the correctness of the program is concerned, but it's a good idea to avoid someone changing them without going via the get/set functions

Comment: @M.M, Yeah i looked into the code, by making them private code of this kind `bool sortTasksByIDAsc(const Task &lhs, const Task &rhs) {
 return lhs.id < rhs.id;
}` will not work.

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313: Well, that could be friend or a member as an overload of operator<

Comment: @M.M Sir can you tell me what will be the best way to input values into `depList` or `pretask` vector when i will be using for loop to set these values for each Task. My cin in while loop is getting ignored after setting this vector to one task.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like the element being printed out each line is the last element inserted, it's likely that you've incorrectly created `static` fields. It would be helpful if you posted the code for your `Task` class. Specifically, the implementation of the constructor, and the private fields I'm assuming you took out of your post. Additionally, I imagine that if you worked towards changing your code into a complete, minimal example, you'd probably find the error yourself. It's hard to tell what's causing your problem without seeing more code.